# For what values of $c$ does the curve $ y = cx^{3} + e^{x} $ have inflection points?

Tags: calculus

For what values of $c$ does the curve $ y = cx^{3} + e^{x} $ have inflection points?

at first I found first derivative $ f^{'}(x) = 3cx^2 + e^{x} $

then second derivative $ f^{''} (x) = 6cx + e^{x} $

now the second derivative should  go from positive to negative or from negative to positive yes?
and I wrote this system
$$ -e^{x} < 6cx < 0 $$

so give me a hint i don't know that to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation $y''=6cx+e^x=0$ as a system
$$\begin{cases}
y=e^x\\
y=-6cx\\
\end{cases}
$$

we see that for $c>0$ there is one and only one solution: one inflection point.

The tangent passing through the origin $(0,0)$ has equation $y=ex$, thus

for negative $c$ we have no solution when $-6c<e$ that is $-\frac{e}{6}<c<0$

for $c<-\frac{e}{6}$ we have two intersection that is two inflection points.

For $c=-\frac{e}{6}$ second derivative is $y''=e^x-ex$ which is zero at $x=1$. This is not an inflection point since third derivative $y^{(3)}=e^x-e$ is zero too at $x=1$.

It happens like in $y=x^4$ where second derivative $y''=12x^2$ is zero at $x=0$ but there is no inflection point since $y^{(3)}(0)=0$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can have an inflection where the second derivative cancels, or

$$6cx+e^x=0.$$

This transcendental equation cannot be solved for $x$, but it can for $c$. If you "decide" an inflection point at $x$, then

$$c=-\frac{e^x}{6x}$$ and it suffices to check the range of $c$. The computation is quite tractable.

---

Note that an extra condition is that the third derivative

$$6c+e^x$$ does not vanish at the same time. This is possible with $x=1$ and $c=-\dfrac e6.$